# Count of no clicks on last 3 emails using data views in marketing cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql, automationstudio, data-views

I am trying to write a query in SFMC where i want create a data extension with people who have not clicked any emails and we have sent them at least 3 emails.

I have the below query but i am getting 0 results. Can anyone correct me?

```
Select distinct s.SubscriberKey,count(c.EventDate) as total_clicks,count(s.EventDate) as total_sends
from [_sent] s
left join [_click] c
on s.JobID = c.JobID and s.ListID = c.ListID and s.BatchID = c.BatchID and s.SubscriberID = c.SubscriberID and c.IsUnique = 1
left join [_job] j
on j.JobID=c.JobID
where c.SubscriberID is NULL and j.EmailName like '%abcd%'
group by s.SubscriberKey
Having count(s.EventDate)>=3 and  count(c.EventDate)<1
```

Comment: I would get rid of the last condition and give it a try: `and count(c.EventDate)<1`

Comment: Tried this, still i get 0 results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though the `count(c.EventDate)<1` part looks indeed suspicious, in reality, it is a valid condition, yet really unnecessary here, since you already have `c.SubscriberID is NULL` for the Left Exclusion Join.

The problem is within your second `LEFT JOIN` which should be between `_Job` and `_Sent` because you want to find records that are **not** in the `_Click` Data View and thus the connection to it will result in empty values from `_Job` and that is why finally condition `j.EmailName like '%abcd%'` cannot be met.

The correct query should look like this -

```
SELECT DISTINCT
s.SubscriberKey,
count(c.EventDate) AS total_clicks,
count(s.EventDate) AS total_sends
FROM [_sent] s
LEFT JOIN [_click] c
ON s.JobID = c.JobID AND s.ListID = c.ListID AND s.BatchID = c.BatchID AND s.SubscriberID = c.SubscriberID AND c.IsUnique = 1
LEFT JOIN [_job] j
ON j.JobID = s.JobID
WHERE c.SubscriberID IS NULL AND j.EmailName like '%abcd%'
GROUP BY s.SubscriberKey
HAVING count(s.EventDate) >= 3
```